# A question about a statement in the paper of C.T.C. Wall

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

‎‎Suppose that  ‎‎$‎‎X$ ‎is ‎a finite ‎2-dimensional CW-complex with free fundamental group ‎and ‎‎$‎‎‎\phi‎ :K ‎\longrightarrow ‎X‎$ is a map which  ‎induces ‎an ‎isomorphism ‎of ‎fundamental ‎groups, where $K$ is a finite bouquet of circles with the wedge point $a$.  Consider the mapping cylinder $M=X\bigcup_{\phi} (K \times \{1\})$‎. ‎Denote $\pi_n (M_{‎\phi‎},K \times \{ 1\} )$  by $\pi_n (\phi )$‎. ‎Recall ‎that ‎an ‎element ‎of ‎‎$‎‎\pi_n (‎\phi‎ )$ ‎is ‎represented ‎by a‎ ‎pair ‎of ‎maps ‎‎$‎‎‎\beta ‎:‎\mathbb{S}^{n-1}‎\longrightarrow ‎K‎$‎ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎‎\gamma ‎:‎\mathbb{D}^n ‎\longrightarrow ‎X‎$‎ ‎with ‎‎$‎‎‎\gamma‎|_{‎\mathbb{S}^{n-1}‎}=\phi‎ \circ ‎\beta‎$. In the paper ''Finiteness conditions for CW-complexes'' of C.T.C.Wall in Propositon 3.3, Wall has mentioned that since  ‎‎$‎‎\pi_2 (‎\phi‎)$ ‎is a‎ ‎free ‎‎$‎‎‎\mathbb{Z}\pi_1  (X)‎$-module‎, then we can attach 2-cells ‎to ‎‎$‎‎K$, ‎necessarily ‎with ‎trivial ‎attaching ‎maps, to make $\phi$ a homotopy equivalence.

My question is that:
What is Wall's mean concerning ''necessarily ‎with ‎trivial ‎attaching ‎maps''?
If his mean is that 2-cells are wedged to the wedge point a, then how can I get to this fact?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attaching map for a 2-dimensional cell is a map $f: S^1 \to K$, and it determines an element $[f]$ of $\pi_1(K)$ (up to conjugacy). What Wall means by trivial attaching maps is that these elements of $\pi_1(K)$ must be trivial. If they weren't, then the map $\pi_1(K) \to \pi_1(K \cup_f D^2) \to \pi_1(X)$ that attaches the cell would send the element $[f] \in \pi_1(K)$ to the trivial element, which contradicts the fact that the map $\phi$ was an isomorphism on $\pi_1$ in the first place.

The homotopy type of the complex you get by gluing 2-dimensional cells only depends on the homotopy classes of the attaching maps (to prove this you typically use multiple applications of the homotopy extension property). Therefore, up to homotopy equivalence it really is the case that you can just attach 2-dimensional cells to the basepoint. The second homotopy group $\pi_2(K \vee \bigvee S^2)$ is a free $\Bbb Z[\pi_1(K)]$-module generated by the copies of $S^2$, and Wall's construction is sending these to a set of generators for $\pi_2(X)$ over $\Bbb Z[\pi_1(X)]$.

Comment: Your explanation is so perfect. Now I understood Wall's mean. Thank you so much for your answer. Could you please explain the construction of $\pi_n (\phi )$ (generators and relations) as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module?

Comment: I mean that assume that we attach 2-cells to $K$, ecessarily ‎with ‎trivial ‎attaching ‎maps, to make $L$ and extend $\phi$ over these cells to get a map $\psi :L\longrightarrow X$ so that $\pi_1 (\psi )=\pi_2 (\psi )=0$ (as Wall has mentioned in his paper, p. 59). Now if $\pi_3 (\psi )$ is free, then how do I describe attaching maps?

Comment: @M.Ramana Every element of $\pi_3(\psi)$ is represented by a pair of a map $\alpha: S^2 \to L$ and a map $\beta: D^3 \to X$ so that $\psi \circ \alpha = \beta|_{S^2}$. You can use the generators of $\pi_3(\psi)$ to get attaching maps $\alpha$ to construct your new space $L \to M$ by attaching 3-cells, and the maps $\beta$ to extend your map from $L$ to a map $M \to X$.

Comment: I understood what is the form of elements of $\pi_3 (\psi )$. But I don't know yet the form of generators and relations of $\pi_3 (\psi )$ as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module exactly . Could you determine them for me exactly?

Comment: In fact, my question is that if $\pi_3 (\psi )$ is free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module, then do 3-cells attach to $L$, necessarily ‎with ‎trivial ‎attaching ‎maps (i.e., are they wedged to L)? For example, you told me in your main answer ''what Wall means by trivial attaching maps is that these elements of $\pi_1 (K)$ must be trivial''. But I couldn't understand relation between trivialness of elements of the form $f:S^1 \longrightarrow K$ and freeness of $\pi_2 (\phi )$.

Comment: @M.Ramana Unless I am mistaken, the map $\psi$ is constructed so that it is an isomorphism on $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ between 2-dimensional CW-complexes. In particular, on universal covers $\tilde \psi: \tilde L \to \tilde K$ is an isomorphism on all homology groups ($H_2 = \pi_2$ is the only nonzero one), which implies that it's a weak equivalence by the Whitehead theorem--therefore $\psi$ itself is a weak equivalence and so I believe that $\pi_n(\psi)$ is trivial for all $n$.

Comment: I'm sorry. No, you have not make a mistake. I wrote my question without precision. I rewrite my question as following:

Comment: Question One. I understood what is Wall's mean about ''necessarily ‎with ‎trivial ‎attaching ‎maps'' in the proof of Proposition 3.3 in the paper by your explanation in your main answer. The only question remains open here for me is that what relation is there  between trivialness of elements of the form $f:S^1 \longrightarrow K$ (as you mentioned in your answer) and freeness of $\pi_2 (\phi )$ as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module?

Comment: Question Two. Suppose that $X$  is a finite (for example) $5$-dimensional CW-complex with free fundamental group and $\phi :K\longrightarrow X‎$ is like before. If $\pi_2 (\phi )$ is free,  we attach 2-cells to K, necessarily ‎with ‎trivial ‎attaching ‎maps, to make $L$ and extend $\phi$  to get a map $\psi :L\longrightarrow X$ so that $\pi_1(\psi )=\pi_2 (\psi )=0$ (as Wall has mentioned in his paper, p. 59). Now my main question is that: if $\pi_3 (\psi )$ is free, then how can I describe attaching maps? in other words,  are they wedged to L again (like previous case)???

Comment: Here is the situation. If you have a map $f: K \to L$ and an element in $\pi_m(f)$, which you use to attach an $m$-cell to $K$ and extend to $K \cup e^m \to L$, then the attaching map is trivial if and only if the boundary map $\pi_m(f) \to \pi_{m-1} K$ takes it to the trivial element. If you want to do this for _all_ the generators of  $\pi_m(f)$, then you need the boundary map $\pi_m(f) \to \pi_{m-1} K$ to be the zero map, or equivalently you need the map $\pi_{m-1} K \to \pi_{m-1} L$ to be injective.

Comment: In the situation you started with, you first had a map $K \to X$ which was an isomorphism, so you could attach 2-cells along trivial attaching maps to hit the generators of $\pi_2(\phi)$. Since $\pi_2(\phi)$ was free, you could attach one cell for each generator to construct a map $L \to X$ so that $\pi_2(L) \to \pi_2(X)$ is an isomorphism. Hence this is injective, so if you further wanted to attach 3-dimensional cells you could do it with trivial attaching maps.

Comment: If $\pi_3(\psi)$ was then free, you could again attach one cell per generator and repeat. However, if at any point you did not have freeness over $\Bbb Z[\pi_1(X)]$ then you would not be able to achieve the injectivity that allows you to make the next attaching maps trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your exact explanation. I found my answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Excuse me, How does freeness of   $\pi_2 (\phi )$ help us to achieve the injectivity of $\pi_2 (L)\longrightarrow \pi_2 (X)$? Could you please give me a reference for these statements?

Comment: This is because $\pi_2(Y \vee S^2) = \pi_2(Y) \times \Bbb Z[\pi_1(X)]$. It is what allows you to pick exactly enough generators so that the map $\pi_2(L) \to \pi_2(X)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I was wondering if I could ask you some questions about the above discussion. Actually, I need your help to understand more about the discussion.  Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You can feel free to ask.

Comment: Dear professor, thank you so much for your favor. Actually, I'm very curious about details  the discussion. That's why I have lots of questions about it. But I don't want to  take up your valuable time. Could you explain for me how to extend the map $\phi :K\longrightarrow X$ to $\psi :L\longrightarrow X$? Thank you. You told in your answer that we must use multiple applications of the homotopy extension property, but I don't know exactly how to do this.

Comment: As we discussed above, $L$ is homotopy equivalent to $K \vee S^2 \vee \dots \vee S^2$. Extending the map $K \to X$ to a map $L \to X$ is determined by choosing based maps $S^2 \to X$, which are determined by the generators of $\pi_2(X)$.

Comment: So we can extend the map $\phi$ by generators of  $\pi_2 (X)$ even if it is not free. Is it true?

Comment: Yes. Freeness is used to pick a _basis_ of pi_2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand all details of the discussion. On the other hand, I'm curios about it. Could you give me a good reference about the attaching and extension and other things which are connected to the discussion? Thank you very much.

Comment: For example, I still don't understand why if $\pi_2 (\phi)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$-module, then $\pi_2 (\psi)$ is an isomorphism:(